# Sparse matrix-matrix multiplication in CUDA using cuSPARSE

Tags: cuda, nvidia, sparse-matrix, gpu

I'm benchmarking the sparse matrix-matrix multiplication on Nvidia K40 using `cuSPARSE` library.
I'm creating my own sparse matrix in `CSR` format and I'm using the `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz` routine of the `cuSPARSE` library.
However, as I increase the data size, an error occurs when calling `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz`, i.e `CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS` is not returned.
Also a `cudaMemcpy` fails and `CUDA_SUCCESS` is not returned.
The code works fine for `8 x 8` and `16 x 16` matrices. However, from `32 x 32` on, this error is observed.

Edit: I'm receiving `CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED` from `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz` for the third matrix size. The execution happens correctly for the first two matrix sizes.

```
#include <cusparse_v2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

// error check macros
#define CUSPARSE_CHECK(x) {cusparseStatus_t _c=x; if (_c != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {printf("cusparse fail: %d, line: %d\n", (int)_c, __LINE__); exit(-1);}}

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
do { \
    cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
    if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
            msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
            __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
        exit(1); \
    } \
} while (0)


double timerval()
{
    struct timeval st;
    gettimeofday(&st, NULL);
    return (st.tv_sec+st.tv_usec*1e-6);
}

// perform sparse-matrix multiplication C=AxB
int main(){ 
double avg_time = 0, s_time, e_time;

cusparseStatus_t stat;
cusparseHandle_t hndl;
cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, descrB, descrC;
int *csrRowPtrA, *csrRowPtrB, *csrRowPtrC, *csrColIndA, *csrColIndB, *csrColIndC;
int *h_csrRowPtrA, *h_csrRowPtrB, *h_csrRowPtrC, *h_csrColIndA, *h_csrColIndB, *h_csrColIndC,*pos;
float *csrValA, *csrValB, *csrValC, *h_csrValA, *h_csrValB, *h_csrValC;
int nnzA, nnzB, nnzC;
int m=4,n,k,loop;
int i,j;
int iterations;
for (iterations=0;iterations<10;iterations++)
{
    m *=2;
    n = m;
    k = m;
    //density of the sparse matrix to be created. Assume 5% density.
    double dense_const = 0.05;
    int temp5, temp6,temp3,temp4;
    int density=(m*n)*(dense_const);
    nnzA = density;
    nnzB = density;
    h_csrRowPtrA = (int *)malloc((m+1)*sizeof(int));
    h_csrRowPtrB = (int *)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
    h_csrColIndA = (int *)malloc(density*sizeof(int));
    h_csrColIndB = (int *)malloc(density*sizeof(int));
    h_csrValA  = (float *)malloc(density*sizeof(float));
    h_csrValB  = (float *)malloc(density*sizeof(float));
    if ((h_csrRowPtrA == NULL) || (h_csrRowPtrB == NULL) || (h_csrColIndA == NULL) || (h_csrColIndB == NULL) || (h_csrValA == NULL) || (h_csrValB == NULL))
    {printf("malloc fail\n"); return -1;}

    //position array for random initialisation of positions in input matrix
    pos= (int *)calloc((m*n), sizeof(int));
    int temp,temp1;

    //  printf("the density is %d\n",density);
    //  printf("check 1:\n");

    //randomly initialise positions
    for(i=0;i<density;i++)
    {
        temp1=rand()%(m*n);
        pos[i]=temp1;

    }
    //  printf("check 2:\n");

    //sort the 'pos' array
    for (i = 0 ; i < density; i++) {
        int d = i;
        int t;

        while ( d > 0 && pos[d] < pos[d-1]) {
            t          = pos[d];
            pos[d]   = pos[d-1];
            pos[d-1] = t;        
            d--;
        }
    }
    // initialise with non zero elements and extract column and row ptr vector
    j=1;
    //ja[0]=1;

    int p=0;
    int f=0;

    for(i = 0; i < density; i++)
    {
        temp=pos[i];
         h_csrValA[f] = rand();
         h_csrValB[f] = rand();
         h_csrColIndA[f] = temp%m;
         h_csrColIndB[f] = temp%m;
        f++;
        p++;
        temp5= pos[i];
        temp6=pos[i+1];
        temp3=temp5-(temp5%m);
        temp4=temp6-(temp6%m);

        if(!(temp3== temp4))
        {   
            if((temp3+m==temp6))
            {}
            else    
            {   
                h_csrRowPtrA[j]=p;
                h_csrRowPtrB[j]=p;
                j++;
            }

        }       
    }

    // transfer data to device

    cudaMalloc(&csrRowPtrA, (m+1)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&csrRowPtrB, (n+1)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&csrColIndA, density*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&csrColIndB, density*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&csrValA, density*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&csrValB, density*sizeof(float));
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
    cudaMemcpy(csrRowPtrA, h_csrRowPtrA, (m+1)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(csrRowPtrB, h_csrRowPtrB, (n+1)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(csrColIndA, h_csrColIndA, density*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(csrColIndB, h_csrColIndB, density*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(csrValA, h_csrValA, density*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(csrValB, h_csrValB, density*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");

    // set cusparse matrix types
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(cusparseCreate(&hndl));
    stat = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrB);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrC);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseSetMatType(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseSetMatType(descrB, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseSetMatType(descrC, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrB, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    stat = cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrC, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    cusparseOperation_t transA = CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE;
    cusparseOperation_t transB = CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE;

    // figure out size of C
    int baseC;
    // nnzTotalDevHostPtr points to host memory
    int *nnzTotalDevHostPtr = &nnzC;
    stat = cusparseSetPointerMode(hndl, CUSPARSE_POINTER_MODE_HOST);
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&csrRowPtrC, sizeof(int)*(m+1));
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");

    s_time=timerval();

    stat = cusparseXcsrgemmNnz(hndl, transA, transB, m, n, k,
    descrA, nnzA, csrRowPtrA, csrColIndA,
    descrB, nnzB, csrRowPtrB, csrColIndB,
    descrC, csrRowPtrC, nnzTotalDevHostPtr );
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    if (NULL != nnzTotalDevHostPtr){
    nnzC = *nnzTotalDevHostPtr;}
    else{
    cudaMemcpy(&nnzC, csrRowPtrC+m, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&baseC, csrRowPtrC, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");
    nnzC -= baseC;}
    cudaMalloc((void**)&csrColIndC, sizeof(int)*nnzC);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&csrValC, sizeof(float)*nnzC);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
    // perform multiplication C = A*B

    for(loop=0;loop<1000;loop++)
    {
        stat = cusparseScsrgemm(hndl, transA, transB, m, n, k,
        descrA, nnzA,
        csrValA, csrRowPtrA, csrColIndA,
        descrB, nnzB,
        csrValB, csrRowPtrB, csrColIndB,
        descrC,
        csrValC, csrRowPtrC, csrColIndC);
        CUSPARSE_CHECK(stat);
    }

    e_time=timerval();

    avg_time=avg_time/1000;
    // copy result (C) back to host
    h_csrRowPtrC = (int *)malloc((m+1)*sizeof(int));
    h_csrColIndC = (int *)malloc(nnzC *sizeof(int));
    h_csrValC  = (float *)malloc(nnzC *sizeof(float));
    if ((h_csrRowPtrC == NULL) || (h_csrColIndC == NULL) || (h_csrValC == NULL))
    {printf("malloc fail\n"); return -1;}
    cudaMemcpy(h_csrRowPtrC, csrRowPtrC, (m+1)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_csrColIndC, csrColIndC,  nnzC*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_csrValC, csrValC, nnzC*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");

    printf ("\n Input size: %d x %d ,Time: %lf and density is %d \n", m,n, avg_time, density); 

    cudaFree(csrRowPtrC);
    cudaFree(csrColIndC);
    cudaFree(csrValC);

    cudaFree(csrRowPtrA);
    cudaFree(csrColIndA);
    cudaFree(csrValA);

    cudaFree(csrRowPtrB);
    cudaFree(csrColIndB);
    cudaFree(csrValB);

    free(h_csrRowPtrC);
    free(h_csrColIndC);
    free(h_csrValC);

    free(h_csrRowPtrA);
    free(h_csrColIndA);
    free(h_csrValA);

    free(h_csrRowPtrB);
    free(h_csrColIndB);
    free(h_csrValB);
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you lifted some of this code from [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/744976/cuda-programming-and-performance/problem-of-two-large-sparse-matrices-multiplication-in-cuparse-/)

As indicated in that posting:

> a failure in `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz` could indicate an underlying problem in CSR matrix formatting.

I'm quite sure that is the problem here.  Your process for generating a properly formatted [CSR matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_row_Storage_.28CRS_or_CSR.29) is broken.

To prove this, add the following code immediately before the indicated comment in your posted code:

```
printf("A RowPtrs: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++) printf("%d ", h_csrRowPtrA[i]);
printf("\nA ColInds: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < nnzA; i++) printf("%d ", h_csrColIndA[i]);
printf("\nB RowPtrs: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) printf("%d ", h_csrRowPtrB[i]);
printf("\nB ColInds: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < nnzB; i++) printf("%d ", h_csrColIndB[i]);
printf("\n");

    // add the above code before this comment:
    // transfer data to device
```

When I do that, recompile, and run, I get output that looks like this:

```
$ ./t730
A RowPtrs:
0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0
A ColInds:
6 7 1
B RowPtrs:
0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0
B ColInds:
6 7 1

 Input size: 8 x 8 ,Time: 0.000000 and density is 3
A RowPtrs:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 12 959542853 1886614883 1702064737 1299346243 1918980205 1232301409 1766154068
A ColInds:
11 6 4 12 11 10 2 13 3 2 8 11
B RowPtrs:
-1688500168 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B ColInds:
11 6 4 12 11 10 2 13 3 2 8 11
cusparse fail: 6, line: 193
```

We see that the first set of CSR-formatted `A` and `B` matrices up to and including the line that starts with `Input size: 8 x 8...` seems to complete without error however the formatting *is in fact broken*.  Empty rows do not have their row pointer starting at zero (row pointers are not allowed to move backward), they have their row pointer starting at the last populated row (so that the number of nonzero elements per row is equal to the current row pointer minus the previous row pointer), *and* the last value in the row pointer sequence points to one element beyond the last element in the matrix (i.e. the last value in the CSR row-pointer array is nnz, the number of non-zero elements).

The next set of A and B matrices (corresponding to the 16x16 pass) are clearly broken.  At a minimum, you have row pointers in both the A and B CSR formatted matrices that are clearly out-of-range.

Your code for creating CSR matrices is just broken.  I suggest you study CSR matrices and create a tool for validating any matrices that you are going to create randomly in this fashion.  [CUSP](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary) has matrix validation functions, and I am sure there are other CSR matrix format validation functions you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Following Robert Crovella's answer, I want to provide a fully worked code implementing matrix-matrix sparse multiplication.

To avoid any ambiguity on sparse matrix format, the code starts from dense matrices and uses `cusparse<t>dense2csr` to convert the matrix format from dense to csr.

The two matrices involved in the code are `A` and `B`. Matrix `B` is a permutation matrix. The code calculates `C = B * A`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse_v2.h>

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseHandle_t handle;    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    /**************************/
    /* SETTING UP THE PROBLEM */
    /**************************/
    const int N     = 4;                // --- Number of rows and columns

    // --- Host side dense matrices
    double *h_A_dense = (double*)malloc(N * N * sizeof(*h_A_dense));
    double *h_B_dense = (double*)malloc(N * N * sizeof(*h_B_dense));
    double *h_C_dense = (double*)malloc(N * N * sizeof(*h_C_dense));

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_A_dense[0] = 0.4612;  h_A_dense[4] = -0.0006;     h_A_dense[8]  = 0.3566;     h_A_dense[12] = 0.0; 
    h_A_dense[1] = -0.0006; h_A_dense[5] = 0.4640;      h_A_dense[9]  = 0.0723;     h_A_dense[13] = 0.0; 
    h_A_dense[2] = 0.3566;  h_A_dense[6] = 0.0723;      h_A_dense[10] = 0.7543;     h_A_dense[14] = 0.0; 
    h_A_dense[3] = 0.;      h_A_dense[7] = 0.0;         h_A_dense[11] = 0.0;        h_A_dense[15] = 0.1; 

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_B_dense[0] = 0.;      h_B_dense[4] = 0.;          h_B_dense[8]  = 1.;         h_B_dense[12] = 0.; 
    h_B_dense[1] = 1.;      h_B_dense[5] = 0.;          h_B_dense[9]  = 0.;         h_B_dense[13] = 0.; 
    h_B_dense[2] = 0.;      h_B_dense[6] = 1.;          h_B_dense[10] = 0.;         h_B_dense[14] = 0.; 
    h_B_dense[3] = 0.;      h_B_dense[7] = 0.;          h_B_dense[11] = 0.;         h_B_dense[15] = 1.; 

    // --- Create device arrays and copy host arrays to them
    double *d_A_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense, N * N * sizeof(*d_A_dense)));
    double *d_B_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B_dense, N * N * sizeof(*d_B_dense)));
    double *d_C_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C_dense, N * N * sizeof(*d_C_dense)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense, h_A_dense, N * N * sizeof(*d_A_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_B_dense, h_B_dense, N * N * sizeof(*d_B_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix A
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;      cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE));  

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix B
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrB;      cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrB));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descrB, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrB, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE));  

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix C
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrC;      cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrC));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descrC, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrC, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE));  

    int nnzA = 0;                           // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix A
    int nnzB = 0;                           // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix B

    const int lda = N;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix

    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row of matrix A
    int *d_nnzPerVectorA;   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVectorA, N * sizeof(*d_nnzPerVectorA)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, N, N, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVectorA, &nnzA));

    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row of matrix B
    int *d_nnzPerVectorB;   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVectorB, N * sizeof(*d_nnzPerVectorB)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, N, N, descrB, d_B_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVectorB, &nnzB));

    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row of matrix A
    int *h_nnzPerVectorA = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVectorA));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVectorA, d_nnzPerVectorA, N * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVectorA), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row of matrix B
    int *h_nnzPerVectorB = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVectorB));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVectorB, d_nnzPerVectorB, N * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVectorB), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix A = %i\n\n", nnzA);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i for matrix = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVectorA[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix B = %i\n\n", nnzB);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i for matrix = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVectorB[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // --- Device side sparse matrix
    double *d_A;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, nnzA * sizeof(*d_A)));
    double *d_B;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B, nnzB * sizeof(*d_B)));

    int *d_A_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices, (N + 1) * sizeof(*d_A_RowIndices)));
    int *d_B_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B_RowIndices, (N + 1) * sizeof(*d_B_RowIndices)));
    int *d_C_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C_RowIndices, (N + 1) * sizeof(*d_C_RowIndices)));
    int *d_A_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices, nnzA * sizeof(*d_A_ColIndices)));
    int *d_B_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B_ColIndices, nnzB * sizeof(*d_B_ColIndices)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, N, N, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVectorA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, N, N, descrB, d_B_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVectorB, d_B, d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices));

    // --- Host side sparse matrices
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(nnzA * sizeof(*h_A));        
    double *h_B = (double *)malloc(nnzB * sizeof(*h_B));        
    int *h_A_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices));
    int *h_A_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnzA * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices));
    int *h_B_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(*h_B_RowIndices));
    int *h_B_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnzB * sizeof(*h_B_ColIndices));
    int *h_C_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(*h_C_RowIndices));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, nnzA * sizeof(*h_A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_RowIndices, d_A_RowIndices, (N + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_ColIndices, d_A_ColIndices, nnzA * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_B, d_B, nnzB * sizeof(*h_B), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_B_RowIndices, d_B_RowIndices, (N + 1) * sizeof(*h_B_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_B_ColIndices, d_B_ColIndices, nnzB * sizeof(*h_B_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nOriginal matrix A in CSR format\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzA; ++i) printf("A[%i] = %f ", i, h_A[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\nOriginal matrix B in CSR format\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzB; ++i) printf("B[%i] = %f ", i, h_B[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (N + 1); ++i) printf("h_A_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (N + 1); ++i) printf("h_B_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_B_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzA; ++i) printf("h_A_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_ColIndices[i]);  

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzB; ++i) printf("h_B_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_B_ColIndices[i]);  

    // --- Performing the matrix - matrix multiplication
    int baseC, nnzC = 0;
    // nnzTotalDevHostPtr points to host memory
    int *nnzTotalDevHostPtr = &nnzC;    

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetPointerMode(handle, CUSPARSE_POINTER_MODE_HOST));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseXcsrgemmNnz(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, N, N, descrB, nnzB, 
                                         d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices, descrA, nnzA, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, descrC, d_C_RowIndices, 
                                         nnzTotalDevHostPtr));
    if (NULL != nnzTotalDevHostPtr) nnzC = *nnzTotalDevHostPtr;
    else {
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&nnzC,  d_C_RowIndices + N, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&baseC, d_C_RowIndices,     sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        nnzC -= baseC;
    }
    int *d_C_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C_ColIndices, nnzC * sizeof(int)));
    double *d_C;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C, nnzC * sizeof(double)));
    double *h_C = (double *)malloc(nnzC * sizeof(*h_C));        
    int *h_C_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnzC * sizeof(*h_C_ColIndices));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrgemm(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, N, N, descrB, nnzB,
                                      d_B, d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices, descrA, nnzA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, descrC,
                                      d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsr2dense(handle, N, N, descrC, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, d_C_dense, N));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C ,           d_C,            nnzC * sizeof(*h_C), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C_RowIndices, d_C_RowIndices, (N + 1) * sizeof(*h_C_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C_ColIndices, d_C_ColIndices, nnzC * sizeof(*h_C_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nResult matrix C in CSR format\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzC; ++i) printf("C[%i] = %f ", i, h_C[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (N + 1); ++i) printf("h_C_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_C_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzC; ++i) printf("h_C_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_C_ColIndices[i]);  

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C_dense, d_C_dense, N * N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            printf("%f \t", h_C_dense[i * N + j]);
        printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: note that there is also a completely worked example in the link I gave in my answer [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/744976/cuda-programming-and-performance/problem-of-two-large-sparse-matrices-multiplication-in-cuparse-/) (although it starts with 2 sparse matrices, omitting the dense-to-sparse conversion).

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry Robert, for some reasons I missed it. Perhaps someone could find it useful to have a fully worked example also on SO (?).

Comment: Agreed and no worries!  I upvoted.  Thanks for all your contributions.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks, Robert.